# Allow users to select a top 10 list from 1000 items in database table

Tags: tables, lists

I have a database table with almost 1000 items, names ,image urls, desciptions etc.

What would be the best way to allow a user to be able to select a top 10 list from  those 1000 items, and then post the list to a new page and send the list to a friend.

This is not a vote script, I Hope I could get a small example and then I could take it from there, in php, mysql.

Thanks

Comment: Are you after some actual PHP / SQL, or just a suggestion for the approach to take so that you can then produce the code yourself?

Comment: well both, anything would be apreciated, I dont now if to put drop down liste or check marks, I know how to display all items from the select (*) from table

Comment: We can't really provide you with the code though. As a UX site we're about the UX problem itself, not the implementation of the solution (we deal with *what* to do, not *how* to do it) but we can probably help with suggesting the right approach to take.

Comment: How familiar are the users going to be with the content of the database? That sounds like the biggest question here. There are plenty of options for list building and sharing, but a 1000 item-long list isn't going to work. You need to categorize the information, and how you do that depends on what the core interaction is. Are users going to be searching for things they know are probably present in the dataset, or are they browsing/discovering content they're not familiar with?

Comment: What is the use case? Why are the lists so long? and why do users want to share a subset? Also what do you mean by top?

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this with simple PHP and MySQL I would suggest you keep track of popularity. Whether that may be in views, buys, clicks, search, etc.  From that you can keep a list of the top popular items as they likely would be far more relevant to all your users.

Normally I would suggest better alternatives that use systems to make contextual recommendations for each individual users, but in some cases that sort of technology may not be easily available. But if you do want that sort of alternative, I would be more than happy to elaborate on that answer as well.

I would suggest against voting though. As it requires to add new functionality that may distract from your main functionality. Unless of course the items themselves don't do anything and there aren't any call to actions like buying, viewing, sharing, etc. The performance metrics that you should associate to each item should be updated regularly to keep the listings fresh. You may not want something that was popular a month ago to still dominate your listings.